# Pig Latin JOIN error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, apache-pig

I am loading two datasets A, B

```
A= LOAD  [datapath]
B= LOAD  [datapath]
```

I want to JOIN all fields of both A and B by id field.Both A and B have common field id and other fields. When I perform JOIN by id:

```
AB= JOIN A by id, B by id;
```

The resulted dataset AB includes two similar columns for the field id, However, it only must show only one column for the id field. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour, when joining two datasets, all columns are included (even those ones which you are joining by)

You can check it [here](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/basic.html#join-inner)

If you want to drop a column you can do it with the `generate` statement. But first you ned to know the position of the undesired column.

If that column is, for instance, in the 3th position

```
C = FOREACH AB GENERATE $1,$2, $4, $5...;
```

**Edit from the comments**
You can also use a generate statement without knowing position. Example:

```
C = FOREACH AB GENERATE A::id AS id, A::foo AS foo, B::bar AS bar;
```

Comment: You can use a generate statement without knowing position (in fact, I wouldn't recommend using position since your code won't be robust if you change a line upstream). For example, `C = FOREACH AB GENERATE A::id AS id, A::foo AS foo, B::bar AS bar;`

Comment: @savagedata that's good to know. I'll update the answer with that. Thanks